# JNA receive a struct containing a string from C/C++

Tags: java, c++, struct, jna, character-arrays

I'm trying to use JNA to get some structs back from a C/C++ library that contains fixed length char arrays.  In C++ since I'm not dynamically allocating anything I can just return the struct back via copy to a calling function... and would like to keep that signature if I can going to Java.  I'm pretty new to JNA and Java so I'm sure I'm just missing something...

A simplified version of the C++ struct looks something like this:

```
 typedef struct MyData_
 {
   int id;
   char name[256];
 } MyData;

 ...

 extern "C"
 MyData fnGetData();
```

The JNA class is like this:

```
 public static class MyData extends Structure
 {
     public static class ByValue extends MyData implements Structure.ByValue {}
     public int id;
     public String name;

     @Override
     protected List getFieldOrder()
     {
         return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "id", "name", });
     }
 }

 MyData.ByValue fnGetData();
```

This gives an error.  I've also tried using `public char[] name = new char[256];` in the class declaration but that's not doing the right thing.

If I follow the example found at http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example12.html I can get it to work but their solution has me allocating the character array on the heap in my C++ library, which I then need to create a 2nd call to go and free the memory when I'm done with it in Java.  I was hopeful I could keep this on the stack and just return a copy.

I can change things up so that I use ByReference and allocate the structure in Java and send it through the parameter list to the C code for filling, but I am not sure how to allocate the fixed length char buffer on the Java side...

Ideally, I'd like to only make one call through JNA and just stick with managed memory.  Any suggestions?  Is it best to just go with the way that is described on that link or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your native structure contains an array of bytes, which may or may not be `NUL`-terminated.  This should be represented by `byte[]` in Java, and use `Native.toString(byte[])` to convert it to a `String`.

You should only use `String` when the native type is `[const ]char *`.